# Splitting date range of dates into two to lists

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

I want to spit the following list of dates:

```
Month=['1 October 2020 to 31 October 2020',
        '1 October 2020 to 31 October 2020',
        '1 October 2020 to 31 October 2020',
        '1 October 2020 to 31 October 2020',
        '1 October 2020 to 31 October 2020']
```

The desired output is as follows:

```
 Month = [['1 October 2020', '31 October 2020'],
        ['1 October 2020', '31 October 2020'],
        ['1 October 2020','31 October 2020'],
        ['1 October 2020', '31 October 2020'],
        ['1 October 2020','31 October 2020']]
```

How can I do this using regex.

I used `Month.str.split('to')` but this is not working properly because October contains `to` as a result splitting October into three strings. Therefore, I guess I have to use `regex` for this. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `' to '` as the partition instead of just `to` -- this matches the input format better anyway since if you split on `to` you'd need to also strip the whitespace.

```
>>> [list(i.split(' to ') for i in Month)]
[[['1 October 2020', '31 October 2020'], ['1 October 2020', '31 October 2020'], ['1 October 2020', '31 October 2020'], ['1 October 2020', '31 October 2020'], ['1 October 2020', '31 October 2020']]]
```